# javascript loop through the array and assign the toFixed(2)

Tags: javascript, arrays

i have a javascript array named as array 
and when i console.log(array); i get

**console**

```
Array[6], Array[6], Array[6], Array[6]
```

and the each array has values

```
0: Array[6]
1: Array[6]
2: Array[6]
3: Array[6]
```

and each array has

```
    0: Array[6]
    0: "Jan"
    1: 5672.4000001
    2: "$5672.4000001"
    3: "<div class='tooltip'>↵ <p><b>Time Period:</b> Jan</p>↵ <p><b>Cost:</b> $5672.4000001</p>↵ <p><b>Data Used:</b> 277 GB</p>↵ </div>"
    4: "color: rgb(66, 133, 244)"
    5: 283626
1: Array[6]
0: "Feb"
1: 4673.62
2: "$4673.62"
3: "<div class='tooltip'>↵ <p><b>Time Period:</b> Feb</p>↵ <p><b>Cost:</b> $4673.62</p>↵ <p><b>Data Used:</b> 228 GB</p>↵ </div>"
4: "color: rgb(66, 133, 244)"
5: 233681
```

and further values are given

now what i want is to fetch the [2] index of each array 
in the first array it is "$5672.4000001" and convert it into the proper format like "$5672.40" upto two decimal places

i can loop through each index as

```
array.forEach(function(data) {

  });
```

but i dont know how to assign the rounding of to two decimal places for each array's data[2]

any help would be appreciated

Comment: That first line of code does not declare "a JavaScript array". It sets the variable `array` to `undefined` (probably).

Comment: If you're dealing with currency, I'd recommend storing it as pennies/cents/whatever, then converting it to $xxx.xx format only when displayed to avoid this sort of rounding issue.

Comment: Check out this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach You'll see that the args being called in the callback give you the index, the current value, and the original array.

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexOf to find where the decimal is placed. Like this:

```
var str = array[2];
var theDot = str.indexOf(".");
var formatedPrice = str.substr(0, theDot+3);
```

`formatedPrice` will allways contain two decimals, like this `"$5672.40"`

(Unless you have more than one decimal, in that case you need  to find the last dot).